# MS ISA Proxy connectivity

Tags: proxy

Why are there so many programs that cannot work through an ISA proxy in Windows.

I can understand programs in OS's other than Windows and/or open sourced programs cannot connect through proxy.  But I see many propitary Windows programs that can't.

Does it have to do with the libraries used in the project, or just plain laziness?

Answer (score 0):

One of the main jobs of a ISA proxy server is to block communication.

So the idea is that systems that are on different sides of the proxy server should stop working, if you do not specifically open for the traffic between these systems.

Comment: But there are still programs that cannot connect even if the ISA proxy allows it.